# Flutter: Stepper Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, stepper

I've implemented the GlobalFormKey() function to validate the stepper widget formfields and it is working.. But the downside is, when the errors are produced on the form, and as you know the stepper widget has step animations right? So when I switch to another step, and go back to the previous step all the errors are gone.. Can anyone help me out with this? If Sample code is needed for further analysis let me know in the comments, thank you for any suggestions or advice when validating forms (:

Comment: Can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the issue

Comment: Alright YeasinSheikh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.